# Find all the Documents with all the elements of an Array field should be within a range, borderline values not included in MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDBI have a collection with documents with schema as following example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec2e8385deff0b"),
    "title" : "The Last Student Returns",
    "ratings" : [10,9]
}
```

I want to find all such documents where all the values inside the "ratings" field is greater than 8 and less than 10. Mind that i am asking all the elements inside the array ratings in each document should between 8 and 10.

result should be like following sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec2e8385deff0b"),
    "title" : "The Last Student Returns",
    "ratings" : [9.1,9.3]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) twice will do the job. In pseudocode:

```
$and(
  $elemmatch($gt(ratings, 8), $lt(ratings, 10)),
  $nor([
    $elemmatch($lte(ratings, 8), $gte(ratings, 10)),
  ])
)
```

$nor is needed because $not in MQL is a field-level operator, not a query-level one.